# Strange scaling of imagebutton in last column of TableLayout

Tags: android, imagebutton, tablelayout

I'm using a TableLayout with 3 rows, and 3 imagebuttons in each row. I want to keep the aspect ratio of the images.

I have defined a layout like this:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Cell"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/empty" >
        </ImageButton>

        <!-- Two more images like above -->

    </TableRow>

    <!-- Two more rows like above -->
</TableLayout>
```

With this layout, I get something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/reoSd.png

As you can see, strange holes between rows in the last column appear. I dont know why, but if I change the TableLayout margin to 0dp, this problem dissapears:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="0dp" >
```

And the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jytix.png

Why this behavior? What I am doing wrong? I have tested this, with many devices on the emulator and I always get the same. As additional information, I have printed the size and padding of the images of the last column and the first dinamically with getHeight() and getWidth()..., and i always get exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, you should use relative layout instead... If you still want to use Table layout, try :

```
TableLayout tableView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableView);
TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, tableView, false);
ImageView imgDis = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerEntryContactPhoto);
    imgDis.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    imgDis.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    // set row height width

TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 50);

    params.topMargin = 0;
    params.bottomMargin = 0;
    params.leftMargin = 0;
    params.rightMargin = 0;
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was very busy, and I havent been able to reply before.

I have been trying to use RelativeLayout, but the problem is... I cant use the weight attribute with RelativeLayout. I should use absolute width, and I was trying to avoid it.

I prefer not to use your Java solution because I'm still a noob with android and I dont understand the code and also, I think using XML to define GUI is better.